# Is it possible to run locally ASP.Net Core with kestrel or an HttpListener in UWP or a desktop bridge application?

Tags: asp.net, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am building an application in ASP.Net Core 1.1  (and soon 2.0) with an API and HTML UI, razor views routing.
I would like also to build a desktop application in Win10, using the existing ASP.Net Core codebase, running in localhost and to communicate with specific UWP APIs.
Is it possible to run the ASP.Net Core in localhost under UWP or via desktop bridge?
using Kestrel or other UWP HttpListener ?  ( I have read that they are working on the later).
I can't rewrite the app in XAML and I would like to avoid Electron.
Also I would prefer to use Chrome as embedded browser, but if it could be only with Edge,  I could survive.  The main problem is  to avoid, by any way, to rewrite our code. without purpose.
thanks

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible. I'm not sure why you want to host ASP.Net Core app in UWP. But as per your description, I'd think [Hosted Web App](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/17/building-a-great-hosted-web-app/) would be what you want.

Comment: Hosted Web App  is on the server, I want off-line, they call it [Hybrid apps – Packaged web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-access-features)    But it is not workable, for this reason  developers prefer Electron.   The reason is that I don't want to rewrite or to modify extensively my HTML/JS UI   and the services .  Is it a valid reason ?   not wasting resources ?

Comment: Also Microsoft  had created only one example  the [JSBrower](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser),  for very simple cases, not really workable, but 2 years now, they did not provide any update, neither they answer in github issues for this project.

Comment: Plus, Microsoft  has promised (one year ago) that they are working  on   HttpListener for UWP and it is in NetStandard2 . Here is the [UserVoice issue and answer](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6229906-implement-httplistener-class)

Comment: did you solve this?